# Sign in with Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication

I have a Google Application Engine for Business and its working now. Now I want to develop a new Java web application and I wanted to know can I implement 'Sing in with' my GAE. In other words I want Sign in to my Java web application only my GAE user. Just like that it is implemented in this site but only for my GAE users.

P.S. I am very new to web development so if the above is possible can you give any reference.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty simple, and described in detail here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/overview#Authentication_Options

Comment: Only one of my application is Google App Engine. Second one is separate Java web application that will be hosted on my server.

Comment: Maybe this could help? http://www.drdobbs.com/article/print?articleId=229401853&siteSectionName=web-development